# Formatting Soap into a PHP query

Tags: php, soap

I have a soap function, called selectCmDevice, that I'm having trouble formatting into a php statement to run a query.  In the WSDL, selectCmDevice looks like this (I've included only the relevant parts);

```
<element name="selectCmDevice">
<complexType>
<sequence>
<element name="StateInfo" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="CmSelectionCriteria" type="tns:CmSelectionCriteria"/>
</sequence>
```

```
<complexType name="CmSelectionCriteria">
<sequence>
<element name="MaxReturnedDevices" nillable="true" type="xsd:unsignedInt"/>
<element name="DeviceClass" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="Model" nillable="true" type="xsd:unsignedInt"/>
<element name="Status" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="NodeName" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="SelectBy" nillable="true" type="tns:CmSelectBy"/>
<element name="SelectItems" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfSelectItem"/>
<element name="Protocol" nillable="true" type="tns:ProtocolType"/>
<element name="DownloadStatus" nillable="true" type="tns:DeviceDownloadStatus"/>
</sequence>
```

```
<simpleType name="CmSelectBy">
<restriction base="xsd:string">
<enumeration value="Name"/>
<enumeration value="IPV4Address"/>
<enumeration value="IPV6Address"/>
<enumeration value="DirNumber"/>
<enumeration value="Description"/>
</restriction>
```

```
<complexType name="ArrayOfSelectItem">
<sequence>
<element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="item" type="tns:SelectItem"/>
</sequence>
```

```
<complexType name="SelectItem">
<sequence>
<element name="Item" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
</sequence>
```

```
<simpleType name="ProtocolType">
<restriction base="xsd:string">
<enumeration value="Any"/>
<enumeration value="SCCP"/>
<enumeration value="SIP"/>
<enumeration value="Unknown"/>
</restriction>
```

```
<simpleType name="DeviceDownloadStatus">
<restriction base="xsd:string">
<enumeration value="Any"/>
<enumeration value="Upgrading"/>
<enumeration value="Successful"/>
<enumeration value="Failed"/>
<enumeration value="Unknown"/>
</restriction>
</simpleType>
```

So, I've written a query to that seems to be accepted when I run it in PHP, but it doesn't pull anything I specify - it pulls everything in the system.  It doesn't accept anything in **insertVariableHere**;

```
$deviceIP = $soapClient->selectCmDevice
(array('StateInfo' => '', 'CmSelectionCriteria' => 
(array('SelectBy'=>'Name','Status'=>'Registered','SelectItems'=>
array('SelectItem[0]'=>
array('Item'=>'insertVariableHere'))))));
```

I'm not sure if soap values for tns are being written properly in php.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to see how the actual XML query looks based on WSDL, run the query in the program [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/). It is designed to get an overview of what is actually sent and received.
Once you know how the xml looks, initially send the entire XML string as a SOAPVAR to the selectCmDevice in PHP:

```
$xml='*copy of xml-request from SoapUI*';
$client=new SoapClient($wsdl,array('trace' => 1, 'exception' => 0));
$param=new SoapVar($xml,XSD_ANYXML);
$result=$client->selectCmDevice($param);
```

Now you sould have a working php-example of your query. From here you can modify your call as desired

Comment: this is an extremely useful application, thank you so much for telling me about it.  It helped me sort through a great deal of the issues and I am eternally grateful.